# Implementation of interaces: Incorrect object type

Tags: java, object, interface, polymorphism

I've kinda run into a problem whilst trying to use the subscriber publisher pattern. I created an interface `Publisher` so I can differentiate between non-Publisher-classes and Publisher-classes. A `Subscriber` should only be able to subscribe to a `Publisher`.

However, how can I get the data I need from a `Publisher` class? Specifically I have got this class `Camera` where I know it has to get data from an `Entity` object. `Entity` implements `Publisher`. Even though that's the case, the compiler doesn't want me to get the data the way I'd like to. How do I circumvent this problem? Unfortunately I can't make an abstract class out of my `Publisher` interface because the classes I want to use it in already `extends` from another class.

```
public class Camera implements Subscribers{
    @Override                                     
    /*compiler error shown: "method does not override or implement 
     *a method from a supertype"
     */
    public void publisherUpdated(Entity e)
    {
        //code that uses the Entity object
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Entity extends JLabel implements Publisher{
    //[...]
}
```

.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public interface Publisher {
    final ArrayList<Subscribers> subs = new ArrayList<Subscribers>();
    public void updateSubscribers(Publisher p);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the `Subscribers` class, it's impossible to tell why the error message is occurring.  But if the method in `Subscribers` looks like `public void publisherUpdated(Publisher e)`, and you change the parameter type to `Entity` in `Camera` as shown in your question, then you will get the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the a method called `getSubscribers()` in the `Publisher` interface and let the implementations of the interface manage the subscribers:

```
public interface Publisher {
    public List<Subscriber> getSubscribers(); 
    // ...
}

public class PublisherImplementation implements Publisher {
    private final List<Subscriber> subscribers = new ArrayList<Subscriber>();
    public List<Subscriber> getSubscribers() {
        return subscribers;
    }
    // ...
}
```